# Hide Vue data from user Vue Devtool

Tags: vue.js

Just a quick question
Any user can see and access the data we use in the Vue model via Vue Devtool.
Imagine you have an employee list saved in Vue Obj and the user can see all other employees' emails etc..
Is there a way to hide data from the user browser devtool? Make sure devtool only shows development mode.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question. But if you build your vue application (In Webpack's production mode) Vue devtools should be disabled

Comment: Hi Danidee, I didn't know Webpack's production mode, Visual studio only gives you Release and Debug option.

Comment: If that data is available in a Vue object that means the data is loaded to the front-end, and anyone with a basic JS know-how can access it. I think you should configure the backend to so that it only returns data the user is allowed to view.

Comment: @AdilSari Yeah webpack has a production mode that disables debugging and optimizes the generated JavaScript and CSS so it can be served efficiently in production. someone has posted a good answer that should get you started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are building a SPA project using vue CLI, the vue dev tools is disabled in production through webpack build by default but when you use vue in a HTML page like a MVC project which vue is added to some of its `.cshtml` files it isn't disabled, and you might need to configure it manually to make it disable.

you can do this by adding the line below before making your vue instance, I mean before `new Vue({ ... })`, add:

```
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

(worked in a MVC project)

and here is an article for this:

[disable vue devtools in production](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/disabling-vue-js-devtools-in-production-3def11812245)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Hamid. It worked with Vue2 but Vue3 says "Cannot set property 'devtools' of undefined" Do you know how to fix this with Vue3, please- I used app.config.devtools = false;

Comment: I didn't know that, I will edit the answer to reflect this if I could figure it out